# Как убрать подсказки о модификаторах доступа в Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать эти подсказки о модификаторах доступа в Intellij idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File -> Settings. В настройках Editor -> Inspections убираешь галочку с Declaration access can be weaker. И нажимаешь на OK

Comment: там где-то был пункт отдельно про package модификатор

Comment: @Maxim, Ты о Package-visible field и Package-visible nested class? Мне, почему-то показалось, что это не очень подходит под конкретный вопрос. Но, может быть кому пригодится... Оставлю пожалуй сдесь.

Comment: Добрался до IDE. Да пункт `Declaration access can be weaker`, там просто несколько настроек внутри и можно оставить в целом пункт, но выбрать, что бы он не предлагал понижение до package.

Answer (score 1):

Ставите курсор на текст с подсказкой. Нажимаете `Alt+Enter`. Выбираете нужный пункт. Нажимаете стрелку вправо и выключаете либо полностью либо только для какой-то части кода